# How to know the replication states in DRBD?

Tags: drbd

Replication states of DRBD are many as shown:

Each volume has over each connection a replication state. The possible replication states are:

Off The volume is not replicated over this connection, since the connection is not Connected.

Established
The DRBD9 and LINSTOR User’s Guide: 11.2. Checking DRBD status
81
All writes to that volume are replicated online. This is the normal state.

StartingSyncS Full synchronization, initiated by the administrator, is just starting. The next possible states are: SyncSource or PausedSyncS.

StartingSyncT Full synchronization, initiated by the administrator, is just starting. Next state: WFSyncUUID.

WFBitMapS Partial synchronization is just starting. Next possible states: SyncSource or PausedSyncS.

WFBitMapT Partial synchronization is just starting. Next possible state: WFSyncUUID.

WFSyncUUID Synchronization is about to begin. Next possible states: SyncTarget or PausedSyncT.

SyncSource Synchronization is currently running, with the local node being the source of synchronization.

SyncTarget Synchronization is currently running, with the local node being the target of synchronization.

PausedSyncS The local node is the source of an ongoing synchronization, but synchronization is currently paused. This may be due to a dependency on the completion of another synchronization process, or due to synchronization having been manually interrupted by drbdadm pause-sync.

PausedSyncT The local node is the target of an ongoing synchronization, but synchronization is currently paused. This may be due to a dependency on the completion of another synchronization process, or due to synchronization having been manually interrupted by drbdadm pause-sync.

VerifyS On-line device verification is currently running, with the local node being the source of verification.

VerifyT On-line device verification is currently running, with the local node being the target of verification.

Ahead Data replication was suspended, since the link can not cope with the load. This state is enabled by the configuration on-congestion optione (see Configuring congestion policies and suspended replication).

Behind Data replication was suspended by the peer, since the link can not cope with the load. This state is enabled by the configuration on-congestion option on the peer node (see Configuring congestion policies and suspended replication).

***Command : drbdadm events2 shows the replication status, 
but it does not  change replication:Established even though "drbdadm pause-sync res_name" command is executed.***

Example:

**node1:~ # drbdsetup events2 --now

exists resource name:test_res role:Primary suspended:no

exists connection name:test_res peer-node-id:0 conn-name:node 2 
connection:Connected role:Secondary

exists device name:test_res volume:0 minor:1 disk:UpToDate client:no quorum:yes

exists peer-device name:test_res peer-node-id:0 conn-name:node2 volume:0

replication:Established peer-disk:UpToDate peer-client:no resync-suspended:no

exists -**

How do i get these states(Ahead, Behind, VerifyTs etc..) in DRBD? The documentation doesn't help me much, can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Most of the descriptions you've pasted into your question hold your answer. For example, you explicitly mention `VerifyT`, and then paste the description from the documentation: "On-line device verification is currently running, with the local node being the target of verification". That's your answer. When an online verification is currently running with the local node being the target of verification. If you search the user guide for online verification, you'll figure out how to trigger that state. Same is true for `Ahead`/`Behind` mode; the description tells you where to look for more info.

Comment: Hey Matt, Thank you for replying. I tried with pausing the replication using drbdadm pause-sync command and tried to check the replication status using the same command "drbdadm events2" , but the replication state was still established, where can i get the updated info that i have paused the replication?

Comment: `drbdsetup events2 --now` works for me with `pause-sync`, but generally I would recommend using `drbdadm status` to look at the status of your DRBD devices. When I use `pause-sync`, this is what I see from the node that was in SyncSource: `exists peer-device name:r0 peer-node-id:0 conn-name:centos7-a volume:0 replication:PausedSyncS peer-disk:Inconsistent peer-client:no resync-suspended:peer done:7.15`